# CompareTo in C#

Tags: c#

I currently have code that allows me to check if a number is within a range. I set up and upper and lower bound and then use code like this.

```
u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 & u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) < 0)
```

This works for me when the numbers are simple for example something between 00 and 08. However what if I just want to get all the numbers and still use the above. How can I set up my compare to include the numbers. I need to set the upperBound to something but what can I set that is greater than the number "9"?

Row keys look like this:

```
01-0000
02-0000
89-0000
99-9999
```

I want to be able to set the upper bound so it is greater than 99-9999

Comment: 10 isn't less than 99 :-(  Isn't CompareTo doing a string comparison?

Comment: @TonyG since you haven't told us what `RowKey` or `lowerBound` is typed as, *how would we know*? You've referred to them as numbers, and as `00` / `08`, and as `"9"` - it is far from clear.

Comment: i added some example of the RowKey

Comment: @TonyG and to be clear; this is all strings, yes?

Comment: @Jodrell - the type of `u` is probably irrelevant; it is the type of `.RowKey` that matters.

Comment: In the interest of variety I suggested an alternative approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using strings to sort in orders other than alphabetical is fraught with pain. You could try using `aa-aaaa` as a hack, but personally I'd be tempted to write a numerical converting sort (a custom comparer), or (probably more efficient) I might add a pre-computed *numerical* equivalent, i.e. so that `"01-0000"` becomes the integer `10000`. Then you just sort on `u.KeyNumericValue` instead. For example, you could do this in the `RowKey` setter (and make the numeric value read-only, and only changed by changing the key).

Comment: +1 its what I'd do but, perhaps its rash to assume that these strings should be sorted numerically.

Comment: @Jodrell I'm not sure that is rash... that seems to be the entire thrust of the question

Answer (score 1):

Implement a customized comparer, like so:

```
public class RowKeyComparer : IComparer
{
    int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        var rowA = (RowKey) a;
        var rowB = (RowKey) b;

        ...
    }
}
```

See also http://support.microsoft.com/kb/320727

Answer (score 0):

Assign the value of *99-9999* to the `upperBound` and modify the comparision statement as the following:

```
u.RowKey.CompareTo(lowerBound) >= 0 & u.RowKey.CompareTo(upperBound) <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your examples are strings, it seems that you want to check that the strings are valid keys. Assuming `minKey = 01-0000` and `maxKey = 99-9999` (inclusive bounds if you like) you could check this with a regex rather than using CompareTo at all.

```
Regex.IsMatch(u.RowKey, @"^\d[1-9]-\d{4}$")
```

would do it.